# Does Quartz's @DisallowConcurrentExecution works across multiple JVMs?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

If I have my job code deployed on two JVMs with JdbcStore, does `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` ensure only one job is running across all JVMs?

Comment: @Jimmy So if I want to ensure one job runs across servers, the only way is to manually check it?

Comment: I misread your question. Your quartz server maintains the execution count, so only one instance per job detail runs .for your reference [link](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example4) and its  [source_link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/quartz/examples/example4/ColorJob.java.html) and [page 17 of this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/files/documentation/Quartz-2.1.x-Documentation.pdf) and [java doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.0.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.java/#DisallowConcurrentExecution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will; this kind of attributes work even with multiple instances. The only important thing here is that this attributes it's based on the JobKey, not the code as described [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html).

Anyway, just as reminder, do not run Quartz on multiple server unless you have a deamon to keep your clock in sync. From Quartz guide:

> Never run clustering on separate machines, unless their clocks are synchronized using some form of time-sync service (daemon) that runs very regularly (the clocks must be within a second of each other). See http://www.boulder.nist.gov/timefreq/service/its.htm if you are unfamiliar with how to do this.